# App Submission - Are iPad Screenshots Optional

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm in the process of submitting my first app to the app store - as my app is designed only for iPhone (not iPad) - is uploading iPad screenshots optional? - Or do I have to show screenshots of my app badly zoomed on an iPad?

Answer (score 8):

iPad screenshots are only necessary for Universal or iPad apps.  You don't need them when submitting an iPhone-only app.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to submit iPad screenshots if your app is universal or targeted for iPad only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are made application for both iPhone and iPad then it's necessary to upload screenshot of iPad app or if you are developing only for iPad then also to upload screenshot of your app.